# equidistant delimiter in between flex items with variable width

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to design a navigation rendered dynamically by a CMS (so I have no control over HTML markup). The menu has a unknown, variable number of items, and all items have a variable, unknown width. I need to layout those menu items in one line with an equidistant spacing in between (easily done with flexbox) and with a visual separator exactly in the middle of the spacing (this is my unsolved problem).

Below is the code I've got so far. The HTML is just an example output, and I can't modify it. I'm also not allowed to use JS. The CSS is from myself and I can fully control it.

```css
.mainnav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.mainnav__item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.mainnav__item + .mainnav__item::before {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mainnav">
  <li class="mainnav__item">
    <a class="mainnav__link" href="#">Short</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainnav__item">
    <a class="mainnav__link" href="#">Looooooooooooooong</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainnav__item">
    <a class="mainnav__link" href="#">Mediuuum</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainnav__item">
    <a class="mainnav__link" href="#">whatever else</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My problem is the red separator line. It should be exactly in the middle, but I don't know how to calculate the horizontal position.

Can anybody tell me a CSS only solution for the delimiter placement?

The solution should work in common, up-to-date browsers (current version of [Android|Win] Chrome, [macOs|iOs] Safari, Firefox, Edge), but also in IE11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to consider `display:contents;`<sup>**1**</sup> within the `li` element and keep the pseudo element in-flow (remove `position:absolute`). This will make the pseudo element and the `a` to be the flex items instead of the `li` element thus `space-between` will do the job.

Simply pay attention to the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) since it's a new feature.

```css
.mainnav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.mainnav__item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:contents;
}
.mainnav__item a {
  background:yellow;
}

.mainnav__item + .mainnav__item::before {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  display:block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mainnav">
  <li class="mainnav__item">
    <a class="mainnav__link" href="#">Short</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainnav__item">
    <a class="mainnav__link" href="#">Looooooooooooooong</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainnav__item">
    <a class="mainnav__link" href="#">Mediuuum</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainnav__item">
    <a class="mainnav__link" href="#">whatever else</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> <sup>**1**</sup> The element itself **does not generate any boxes**, but its children and
>   pseudo-elements still generate boxes and text runs as normal. For the
>   purposes of box generation and layout, the element **must be treated as**
>   **if it had been replaced in the element tree by its contents** (including
>   both its source-document **children** and its **pseudo-elements**, such as
>   ::before and ::after pseudo-elements, which are generated before/after
>   the element’s children as normal).<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#valdef-display-contents)</sup>

Another idea is to adjust `flex-grow` and use border instead of relying on `space-between`:

```css
.mainnav {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.mainnav__item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-grow:2; /*middle elements need to grow twice that edge element*/
  text-align:center;
  border-left:1px solid red;
  border-right:1px solid red;
}
.mainnav__item a {  
background:yellow;
}
.mainnav__item:first-child {
  flex-grow:1;
  text-align:left;
  border-left:none;
}
.mainnav__item:last-child { 
  flex-grow:1;
  text-align:right;
  border-right:none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mainnav">
  <li class="mainnav__item">
    <a class="mainnav__link" href="#">Short</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainnav__item">
    <a class="mainnav__link" href="#">Looooooooooooooong</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainnav__item">
    <a class="mainnav__link" href="#">Mediuuum</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainnav__item">
    <a class="mainnav__link" href="#">whatever else</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a really nice and simple solution, but I have to support IE11 :-(